# Problems with a global variable

Tags: theming

I have the following code:

```
$a='1';

function check() {
  global $a;

  if ($a == '1') {
    return "1";
  }
  else {
    return "2";
  }

  var_dump(check());
}
```

When I run this code stand alone, its output is `string(1) "1"`; when I use the code inside page-front.tpl.php the output is `string(1) "2`.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Drupal includes the template file, your declaration of `$a = '1'` is not in the global scope. You need to declare it as such:

```
global $a;
$a = '1';
```

Since you're diving into the realm of global variables though, I'd recommend using a more distinctive name, or figuring out how to avoid globals altogether.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041471/where-to-declare-variables-common-to-different-include-files-in-a-module-drupal/6042617#6042617 for ways to avoid global variables.